# How to escape ’ in this textarea so that onblur and onfocus will work?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

**My Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/jqEwF**

The textarea below contains some javascript to clear the text when the user clicks and puts the default text back if the user does not type anything.

I need to escape the `’` so that the javascript will work

I've tried `&#39;` and just `'` and when I click inside the textarea (`onfocus`) the text does not go away and I get this error in the console:
[image]

However when I try `&quot;` it will work! But I need a `’` or a `'` not `"`

```
<div id="the-accept-textarea">
    <textarea id="accept-response-text" rows="5" cols="50"
    value="I’d be happy to make this introduction if possible. Contact me at your convenience."
    onblur="if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = 'I’d be happy to make this introduction if possible. Contact me at your convenience.';}"
    onfocus="if (this.value == 'I’d be happy to make this introduction if possible. Contact me at your convenience.')
    {this.value = '';}">I’d be happy to make this introduction if possible. Contact me at your convenience.
    </textarea>
</div>
```

How would you handle this?

---

**UPDATE**
trying this

```
var defaultValue = 'I\'d be happy to make this introduction if possible. Contact me at your convenience.'
var txtArea = document.getElementById("accept-response-text");
console.log('txtArea = '+txtArea);
console.log(defaultValue);
txtArea.value = defaultValue;

txtArea.focus = function() {
    console.log('inside focus');
    if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
        console.log('value is defaultValue');
        this.value = '';
    }
}
txtArea.blur = function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

However the focus and blur aren't working, but it is setting the value via Javascript to the textarea

```
<textarea id="accept-response-text" rows="5" cols="50" value=""></textarea>
```

Comment: `\'` It may be easier to read your code if you use a script block to define your blur/focus functions.

Comment: Do not use inline events.

Comment: Do you mean `'` or `‘`? One is a regular ASCII single quote, the other is a `&rsquo;`. Note that `‘` should not be used for things like "I'd" and is used only for quoting phrases.

Comment: ' as in I'm, I just created a codepen here: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/jqEwF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/nk5mf/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var txtArea=document.getElementById("accept-response-text");
  txtArea.onfocus=function() {
    if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
      this.value = '';
    }
  }
  txtArea.onblur=function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
      this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
  }
}
```

---

*UPDATE*

Here is a version with placeholder and support for browsers without placeholders

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/PVnHZ/)

```
function hasPlaceHolder() {
  var i = document.createElement('input');
  return 'placeholder' in i;
}    
window.onload=function() {
  var txt_area_accept = document.getElementById("accept-response-text");
  if (!hasPlaceHolder()) {
    txt_area_accept.defaultValue=txt_area_accept.getAttribute("placeholder");
    txt_area_accept.onfocus = function() {
      if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
      }
    }
    txt_area_accept.onblur = function() {
      if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind a look at this code here? http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/jqEwF thanks!

Comment: Sorry, been doing too much jQuery - it is onfocus and onblur. And the value needs to be in the textarea, not in a var - see update

Comment: I improved my version :)

Answer (score 1):

You can escape them with \

```
if (this.value == '') {
    this.value = 'I\'d be happy to make this introduction if possible. Contact me at your convenience.';
}
```

Comment: the \' did work! However I'm trying to combine your answer with @mplugjan to solve my problem, no success yet

Comment: what's wrong with it? Also, if you don't have to support older browsers, the HTML5 standard allows for a "placeholder" attribute that you might try. see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: the blur and focus does not work, just created a codepen here, do you see what is wrong?: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/jqEwF

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted in your update is correct, except that for adding events you assign to the `on​focus` and `on​blur`, not just `focus` and `blur`.

That said, you should really be using the `placeholder` attribute instead of what you're currently using.

Comment: My mistake. Was thinking in jQuery. With the placeholder you again will have fun with quotes and IE does not support it on the most popular versions

Comment: It works in IE10, and if people aren't using that version it's because they've deliberately chosen to disable Windows Update. So sod them right back. Besides, `placeholder` information should NOT be essential or a sustitute for a proper label, for usability reasons.

Comment: See my update. Alas in the real world where I live, I need to support IE8 on 9000 boxes that cannot install IE9 because XP does not support that. So I cannot wave IE8 goodbye. And it is only a very short time ago I supported IE6